# How to open a hosted PDF inside a windows 8 metro application?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, webview, windows-8

I have a PDF hosted on the server. I need to open inside the application without having to leave it and go to a web browser and never being able to come back to my previous page. Is it doable in a webview control? links in a webview opens normally but a link such as: http://www.interstatecontainer.com/x/example.pdf won't open! So any idea? thx!

Comment: Are you asking if its possible to display the contents of a PDF inside your application?  The answer is of course its possible you just have to write the code to read the PDF file.  Which leads to the question "What have you tried exactly?".

Comment: It's possible to open a PDF inside your application if you use a PDF library for WinRT, a search on the internet (or StackOverflow) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can open it in windows 8 media viewer using file Storage and Launch that is the only way, no feature is available to do it inside the app!